# Can the bitwise AND of some positive integers be negative?

Tags: bit-manipulation

**Can the bitwise AND of some positive integers be negative?**

Let's say I have some numbers 1,2,3..N. For example, take N=7 and I want to find a subarray which results me in a negative result after  bitwise AND operation.

Taking 4,5,6,7 gives me 4(100) but what subarray(for any N) could give me negative result?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the bitwise AND of some positive integers be negative?

No, it can't.

A negative number has the top bit set. All positive numbers have the top bit unset. A zero bit `AND` a zero bit results in a zero bit.  This applies to any number of bitwise `AND` operations performed on any number of positive integers.

And it also applies if you include zero.

In fact, if you perform an bitwise AND on a collection of integers, the result will only be negative if **all** of the integers are less than zero.

---

Note that above is for [twos' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary representations.  All modern mainstream computer instruction sets use twos' complement to represent integers.

With [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) you actually have two zeros +0 and -0.  But if you treat -0 as negative then the same logic applies.

Bitwise AND'ing of floating point number representations ... and treating the results as numbers ... doesn't make a lot of sense.  So I haven't considered that.

Answer (score 0):

(In most/commonly used encodings) sign is stored in first bit.

For first bit to be 1 (meaning negative number) after AND, both bits need to be 1 before that. So it means only 2 negative numbers can make a negative number with AND.

This is true both for [integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and [floats (IEEE754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) (the most common int and float implementations) but basically anything that can store negative numbers has to store the sign somewhere... and as positive numbers are the "default", it's minus that gets marked as 1.